# Magento 1.9.3 category collection

Tags: magento-1.9, category, overrides, frontend

I want to sort all categories & subcategories with a custom attribute to show on front end. So I need to modify the code. 
Can anyone tell me the file from where the all categories & subcategories are fetched in front end. I need to do some modification in it but I don't know where that code is.

Comment: you mean the top menu?

Comment: Yes.everywhere where all categories are listed in frontend.So I guess there will be one common function for it.

Comment: Actually I want to sort those categories & subcategories with a custom attribute. So I need to modify the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by overriding **Mage_Catalog_Model_Observer** observer & placed my logic inside **_addCategoriesToMenu()**  & used **ksort** to sort by custom attribute.